# Which DJango Authentication Backend

Tags: python, django

My application requirement is to use our LDAP directory to authenticate a User based on their network login.  I setup the LDAP correctly using ldap3 in my system.py. I'm able to bind to a user and identify credentials in python, not using Django.  Which authentication backend would I set Django up to use to make my login function as I want?

Comment: If either answer helped you come to your conclusion. Please accept an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad question and I am not sure your experience with Django so without more information I would suggest trying [this](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap) or [this](http://fle.github.io/combine-ldap-and-classical-authentication-in-django.html)

Comment: I have plenty of experience with MVC architecture, but very little with Django and LDAP/User Authentication.  I'm not looking to add a new user to my application, i just want to authenticate using the network login/password with ldap and display user information once logged in.

Comment: The first link's project description states: "django-python3-ldap

django-python3-ldap provides a Django LDAP user authentication backend for Python 2 and 3.

Features

Authenticate users with an LDAP server.
Sync LDAP users with a local Django database.
Supports custom Django user models.
Works in Python 2 and 3!"  Both @FlipperPA and I linked to the django-python3-ldap which should handle your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Python 3 and have used the excellent `django-python3-ldap` package with both OpenLDAP and Active Directory from Django 1.6 through 2.0. You can find it here:

https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

It is a well maintained package that we've been able to use as we upgrade Django from version to version.